# Android RecycleView Adapter (EditText) implementing TextWatcher

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textwatcher, android-viewholder

I am trying to implement a TextWatcher for an edit text inside a Viewholder of a RecycleView. When edittext has been edited, I want to get the position of the adapter to get other information on that row inside the recycleview.

I am not sure whether to create a custom textwatcher which takes in viewholder as an argument (so that it can call getAdapterPosition) because when data is changed, I am afraid the edittext could be using a different viewholder when recycleview recycles the content.

```
 public static class DIViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView invName;
        EditText invWasted;
        EditText invEnding;
        EditText invAdded;

        DIViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            invName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.di_inventory_name);
            invAdded = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.di_inventory_added);
            invWasted = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.di_inventory_wasted);
            invEnding = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.di_inventory_end);
        }
    }


   @Override
    public DIViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item_daily_inventory, viewGroup, false);
        DIViewHolder pvh = new DIViewHolder(v);

        return pvh;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this 

       public static class DIViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements TextWatcher {
                TextView invName;
                EditText invWasted;
                EditText invEnding;
                EditText invAdded;

                DIViewHolder(View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);
                    invName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.di_inventory_name);
                    invAdded = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.di_inventory_added);
                    invWasted = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.di_inventory_wasted);
                    invEnding = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.di_inventory_end);
                    invName.addTextChangedListener(this);
                }

         @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    /* Use this position to retrieve the object for the row and make the 
    changes, preferably have an interface defined which would communicate back the 
position to activity / fragment; Do data object changes there. */ 
                     RowObject object = yourRowObjectsList.get(position);
                     //Do changes to your row object.
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            }
```